# CSS Two Column Setup with float, height equality and vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to have a layout with a header, footer, and two columns of content. So far, an answer in an another forum got me this far: http://jsfiddle.net/bolucpap/FZek3/ (See below for source HTML and CSS). What I want to achieve is that the list with the less lines (in this example, List B, but dynamic data may mean the situation is reversed) have a container of equal height as that of the list with more lines (List A in this example). Also, I want to have the lists vertically centered in their containers. Anyway to do that with just HTML and CSS, or will I have to interfere using JavaScript?

HTML:

```
<div class="headerfooter">
    Header Text
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        List A:
        <ul>
            <li>Item A1</li>
            <li>Item A2</li>
            <li>Item A3</li>
            <li>Item A4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
        List B:
        <ul>
            <li>Item B1</li>
            <li>Item B2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="headerfooter">
    Footer Text
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#leftcolumn {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -2px
}
#rightcolumn {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
    margin-right: -2px
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
#container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.headerfooter {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just create a table? if you need ie support use table and td tags instead of display: table and display: table-cell.

box-sizing here is needed for borders to be counted as part of containers' width. but you can go without it

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#leftcolumn {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#rightcolumn {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try css `column-count`:

```
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count